# Dados nao salvos no banco de dados em php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou com o seguinte codigo de um formulario para que o cliente possa dar sua opiniao, no navegardor ele mostra amensagem de sucesso, porem nao grava no banco de dados. alguem pode ajudar?

```
<?php 

$Nome   = $_POST ["nome"];  
$Cidade = $_POST ["cidade"];    
$Estado = $_POST["estado"]; 
$Email  = $_POST ["email"]; 
$Assunto = $_POST ["assunto"];  
$Mensagem = $_POST ["mensagem"];    


//conectando com o localhost - mysql
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$conexao)
    die ("Erro de conexçao com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
//conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db("mirror",$conexao);
if (!$banco)
    die ("Erro de conexçao com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());



$query = "INSERT INTO `contato` ( `nome` , `cidade` , `estado` , `email` , `assunto` , `mensagem`,'' ) 
VALUES ('$Nome', '$Cidade', '$Estado', '$Email', '$Assunto', '$Mensagem', '')";

mysql_query($query,$conexao);

echo "Sua mensagem, foi recebida com sucesso!<br>Agradecemos a atençao.";
?>
```

Comment: Fica dificil sem saber a modelagem do BD, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizar esse código:

```
<?php 

$Nome   = $_POST["nome"];  
$Cidade = $_POST["cidade"];    
$Estado = $_POST["estado"]; 
$Email  = $_POST["email"]; 
$Assunto = $_POST["assunto"];  
$Mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];    


//conectando com o localhost - mysql
$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$conexao)
    die ("Erro de conexçao com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());
//conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysql_select_db("mirror",$conexao);
if (!$banco) or die ("Erro de conexçao com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());

    $query = "INSERT INTO `contato` ( `nome` , `cidade` , `estado` , `email` , `assunto` , `mensagem`) 
    VALUES ('$Nome', '$Cidade', '$Estado', '$Email', '$Assunto', '$Mensagem')";


    $insert = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe um problema de sintaxe em:

```
(`nome` , `cidade` , `estado` , `email` , `assunto` , `mensagem`,'' )
                                                                 ^^^^
```

O `''` no final, de ambos, não faz sentido algum e provavelmente no primeiro dará erro de sintaxe.

Para isto remova a última "coluna", logo:

```
(`nome` , `cidade` , `estado` , `email` , `assunto` , `mensagem`)
```

Então, remova também a respectiva coluna no `VALUE`:

```
('$Nome', '$Cidade', '$Estado', '$Email', '$Assunto', '$Mensagem')
```

---

No final terá isto:

```
INSERT INTO `contato` 
            (`nome` , `cidade` , `estado` , `email` , `assunto` , `mensagem`)
VALUES      ('$Nome', '$Cidade', '$Estado', '$Email', '$Assunto', '$Mensagem')
```

---

Considere também:

1. Existe problemas de segurança.
2. Está utilizando a API obsoleta (`mysql_*`) *que já foi abandonada no PHP 7*.

Comment: O PROBLEMA ERA MESMO ESSE MYSQL_* , COM PHP7 FOI RESOLVIDO.