# Problemas ao salvar informações no Banco de Dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho este código, mas por algum motivo não esta salvando as informações no banco de dados.
Alguém pode me explicar o que esta errado no código ?

```html
<?php
    require_once('functions.php');
    add();
?>

<h2>Novo Cliente</h2>

<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-7">
            <label for="name">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="customer['name']">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" name="customer['cpf']">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<!--/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Este código esta em outro arquivo-->
<?php
function add() {
 if (!empty($_POST['customer'])) {
  $customer = $_POST['customer'];
  save('pessoa', $customer);
  header('location: index.php');
 }
}
?>
<!--/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Este código esta em outro arquivo-->
<?php
function save($table = null, $data = null) {
 $database = open_database();
 $columns = null;
 $values = null;
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  $columns .= trim($key, "'") . ",";
  $values .= "'$value',";
 }
 $columns = rtrim($columns, ',');
 $values = rtrim($values, ',');
 $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . "($columns)" . " VALUES " . "($values);";
 try {
  $database->query($sql);
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Registro cadastrado com sucesso.';
  $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Nao foi possivel realizar a operacao.';
  $_SESSION['type'] = 'danger';
 }
 close_database($database);
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Tens alguma mensagem de erro para que possamos ajudá-lo melhor?

Comment: Talvez as respostas dessa pergnta te ajude. 
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192239/dados-nao-salvos-no-banco-de-dados-em-php?rq=1

Comment: Não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro, simplesmente roda tudo, mas não insere no banco.
já coloquei o var_dump() nas variáveis e elas estão pegando os valores corretos do html.
E estou usando o mysqli_

Comment: Já verificou se a classe de conexão está funcionando?

Comment: Já tentou colocando o header location depois da inserção no BD?

Comment: A classe de conexão esta funcionando corretamente.
Acabei de colocar o header location depois da inserção, mais mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Essa pergunta é ampla demais. É preciso eliminar o máximo de variáveis possível, do jeito que está você simplesmente copiou o código e espera que o pessoal resolva o seu problema. Verifique se a conexão com a base de dados funciona; se a função `save()` está a ser executada; se a função `add` é chamada, uma vez que ela é responsável por chamar a função `save`... Tente isolar você o problema para que seja mais fácil ajudá-lo. Um sinal de que a pergunta precisa ser reescrita é a quantidade de comentários questionando se você já tentou X ou Y.

Comment: Pega o valor de `$sql`, roda direto no banco e vê se funciona.

Comment: É alguma outra coisa então. Testei o seu código exatamente como está na pergunta e está inserindo normalmente no meu banco.

Comment: Comenta o redirecionamento header location para ficar na mesma página e veja se retorna algum erro. Acho que o problema pode estar nessa função `open_database()`

Comment: Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar. 
O problema era um erro de digitação no nome de uma coluna no  bando de dados.
Consegui descobrir depois que fiz o que o Francisco disse, Obrigado!

Comment: Disponha! =) @w.rock